# Icons on UIImage disappears

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm having trouble with the icons I put on default when the app is launched. They don't appear but when I replace it with a photo taken from another controller, it doesn't disappear. Here is part of my code

I tried setting some conditionals but so far doesn't work.

```
//Default images
    let defImage1: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "media")
    let defImage2: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "media2")

class PDFViewViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {


    //Asset image 
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    var secondImage: UIImage? = nil
    var codigo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "code") as? String

    //UI Conections
    @IBOutlet weak var productPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barcodePhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var invNumb: UITextField!  

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()

        //declaring default image to image view

        productPhoto.image = defImage1
        barcodePhoto.image = defImage2

        //Assign new image to the view

        invNumb.delegate = self

        if self.invNumb != nil && self.productPhoto != defImage1 {
            if image != UIImage(named: "media") {              
               saveImage(image: self.image!, withName: "assetPicture") 
            }     
        } else {
            productPhoto.image = defImage1
        }

        let theSavedImage = getImage(imageName: "assetPicture")
        productPhoto.image = theSavedImage

        //Assign values to fields

        invNumb.text = codigo

        if barcodePhoto != nil {
            if productPhoto != nil {
                saveImage(image: self.secondImage!, withName: "barcodePicture")               
            }

        } else {
            barcodePhoto.image = defImage2
        }

        let theSecondSavedImage = getImage(imageName: "barcodePicture")
        barcodePhoto.image = theSecondSavedImage
    }

    //Save asset image function
    func saveImage(image: UIImage, withName name: String) {

        let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 400)!)
        let paths =     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let docs = paths[0] as NSString
    let name = name
    let fullPath = docs.appendingPathComponent(name)
    _ = imageData.write(toFile: fullPath, atomically: true)

    }
```

When you tapped the image it will open the camera and save the photo you take inside the image view if you don't have any photo taken, then it stays as the defImage. But when you tapped one image, the other one disappears.

Comment: Try moving `let defImage1: UIImage? =...` to inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thanks! Already tried it but it's still not working